# Linq to Entities left join return 0 records

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am working on condensing two linq queries into one query. Basically what I am trying to achieve with the following query is to get all information related to a user, regardless of if they have any orders or not.

As I have written the query currently, it works perfectly, as long as there is at least one order for the user id that I am passing into to method.

It's my understanding that the `.DefaultIfEmpty()` is linq's equivalent of a SQL left join, however the following query is returning `0` records for any user that has not yet placed an order.

**The Query**

```
var orders = (from u in db.people where u.id == UserId
                      join o in db.product_transactions.DefaultIfEmpty() on u.id equals o.user_id
                      join sta in db.order_statuses.DefaultIfEmpty() on o.order_status equals sta.id
                      join ship in db.shipping_types.DefaultIfEmpty() on o.shipping_type equals ship.shipping_id
                      select new { o, u, sta, ship }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to create a Left Join

1) using `into` and `from`

```
 join o in db.product_transactions on u.id equals o.user_id into og
 from o in og.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

2) using `from` and `Where`

```
from o in db.product_transactions.Where(x => u.id == x.user_id).DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Answer (score 2):

`.DefaultIfEmpty()` is not the left join syntax.  `.DefaultIfEmpty()` is the part of the left join syntax that will give you the default value if the cell is null.

[An example left join from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx), note the into and from.

```
var query = from person in people
            join pet in pets on person equals pet.Owner into gj
            from subpet in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { person.FirstName, PetName = (subpet == null ? String.Empty : subpet.Name) };
```